# Why is peerJS showing me this error in Angular?

Tags: angular, peerjs

My program is simple a have 2 sessions, one is who create the host, and the other is who join the host.
The way I do this is: A button leads to host component where a user creates a peer with a personalized ID and in a home component show the created hosts showing the ids so any other client can join to wherever he wants to join, and in fact this works with any problem, at this point peer is on in that ID. Once you click to a host home component send the id like parameter, the room component creates a connection to the host with that id like this:

```
this.router.params.subscribe(params=>{
  this.id = params['id']
  console.log(params)
  this.server.emit('join',this.id)
  let conn = this.peerService.joinHost(this.id)
  conn.on('open', () => {
     console.log('Connected to host with peer ID: ' + conn.peer);
  });
})
```

joinHost is a function in my peer service, that function is this:

```
joinHost(hostID){
console.log("uniendo a:" +hostID)
if(hostID!=undefined){
  this.conn = this.peer.connect(hostID);
}
return this.conn
}
```

As you can see i'm following the documentation, so `this.peer` is a variable in my service `peer:Peer`.

The error I get is:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'connect')

The first thing I think was making the mistake is that this connection to the host is starting in a `ngOnInit` function so maybe the id was undefined at the beginning but doesn't, so the only conclusion i get is the connect function but documentation isn't help me enough. I don't know how to proceed, if anyone have a clue please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your joinHost function, you're trying to access this.peer.connect(hostID), which means this.peer should be an instance of the Peer object that you've created earlier.
2. You mentioned that this.peer is a variable in your peerService, and it is initialized as peer: Peer. You should ensure that you properly initialize the this.peer object before you try to use it. It seems like you're missing the part where you create the Peer instance.

here is could be the solution:

```
// Make sure to import Peer from the PeerJS library at the top of your service file.
import Peer from 'peerjs';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PeerService {
private peer: Peer; // Declare a private property to hold the Peer instance

constructor() {
    // Initialize the Peer instance in the constructor
    this.peer = new Peer(); // You can also pass in options here if needed
}

// Rest of your code...

joinHost(hostID) {
    console.log("uniendo a:" + hostID);
    if (hostID !== undefined) {
    this.conn = this.peer.connect(hostID);
    }
    return this.conn;
}

// Rest of your code...
}
```